# Extract specific xml node from duplicate ones in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, extract, oracle-xml-db

Given is the value of "my_xml" column in "XYZ" table

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<India>
  <city>
    <string>ADI</string>
    <string>Ahmedabad</string>
  </city>
  <city>
    <string>GNR</string>
    <string>Gandhinagar</string>
  </city>
  <city>
    <string>PUN</string>
    <string>Pune</string>
  </city>
  <city>
    <string>RJT</string>
    <string>Rajkot</string>
  </city>
</India>
```

I am trying to extract value of second `string` node where first `string` node value is `ADI`

Output should be "Ahmedabad" only

Failed attempts:

```
select t.my_xml.extract('/India/city/string[2]/text()').getStringVal() from XYZ t where t.my_xml.existsNode('/India/city[string[1] = "ADI"]') = 1;
```

Output for above query is `AhmedabadGandhinagarPuneRajkot`

Expected output: `Ahmedabad`

How to extract specific node value for `string` node here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to select the node that *has* the ADI text as first string.

Try this:

```
select 
    t.my_xml.extract('//city[./string[1]/text() = "ADI"]/string[2]/text()').getStringVal()
from XYZ t
    where t.my_xml.existsNode('/India/city[string[1] = "ADI"]') = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `XMLTable` to extract the values:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   XYZ x,
       XMLTable(
         '/India/city'
         PASSING x.my_xml
         COLUMNS string1 CHAR(3)      PATH './string[1]',
                 string2 VARCHAR2(20) PATH './string[2]'
       ) t
WHERE  t.string1 = 'ADI';
```

Comment: Just for my curiosity, any advantage of using XMLTable over extract() ?

Comment: @Kishan [`EXTRACT()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions068.htm#SQLRF00640) and [`EXTRACTVALUE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions069.htm#SQLRF06173) are both deprecated in Oracle 12c (but included for backwards compatibility) - Oracle recommends using `XMLTable` instead.

Comment: @Kishan apart from that if you want multiple values then you only need to call `XMLTable` once - compare that to the `EXTRACTVALUE` query where it is called once in the `SELECT` clause and then you need to call it a second time (or `EXISTSNODE`) in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: My concern is size of string1 and string2 is not fix (given by external user). Any alternative of passing size while column declaration?

Comment: @Kishan Use `VARCHAR2(4000)` or some sufficiently large value instead. Or you can go back to the external user and get the specification for the data exchange format being used.

Comment: @Kishan Oracle's specification for [`XMLTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions269.htm#SQLRF06232) makes it appear that the datatype is mandatory but it appears to work without the datatype - so you could just omit it.

Answer (score 0):

1) With xmlquery and flwor xquery

```
select xmlcast( xmlquery('for $i in ./India/city where $i//string[1]/text() = $cond return $i/string[2]/text()' passing xmltype(q'~<India>
  <city>
    <string>ADI</string>
    <string>Ahmedabad</string>
  </city>
  <city>
    <string>GNR</string>
    <string>Gandhinagar</string>
  </city>
  <city>
    <string>PUN</string>
    <string>Pune</string>
  </city>
  <city>
    <string>RJT</string>
    <string>Rajkot</string>
  </city>
</India>~'), 'ADI' as "cond"    returning content) as varchar2(20)) result  from dual;
```

2) If you're expecting more than one row try xmltable.

```
select *  from xmltable('$doc/India/city' passing xmltype(q'~<India>
  <city>
    <string>ADI</string>
    <string>Ahmedabad</string>
  </city>
  <city>
    <string>GNR</string>
    <string>Gandhinagar</string>
  </city>
  <city>
    <string>PUN</string>
    <string>Pune</string>
  </city>
   <city>
    <string>ADI</string>
    <string>Ahmedabad</string>
  </city>
  <city>
    <string>RJT</string>
    <string>Rajkot</string>
  </city>
</India>~') as "doc" 
columns 
   string1 varchar2(20) path'./string[1]/text()'
   , string2 varchar2(20) path'./string[2]/text()'

)
where string1='ADI'
```

and xmltable with flwor xquery

```
select column_value  from xmltable('for $el in $doc/India/city where $el//string[1]/text() = "ADI" return $el/string[2]/text()' passing xmltype(q'~<India>
  <city>
    <string>ADI</string>
    <string>Ahmedabad</string>
  </city>
  <city>
    <string>GNR</string>
    <string>Gandhinagar</string>
  </city>
  <city>
    <string>PUN</string>
    <string>Pune</string>
  </city>
   <city>
    <string>ADI</string>
    <string>Ahmedabad</string>
  </city>
  <city>
    <string>RJT</string>
    <string>Rajkot</string>
  </city>
</India>~') as "doc" )
;
```